# Maximum number of values we can have in IN clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Is there a limit to the maximum number of values we can have in the in clause

```
sql_query = """SELECT * FROM table1
               WHERE column1 IN %(list_of_values)s
               ORDER BY CASE
               WHEN column2 LIKE 'a%' THEN 1
               WHEN column2 LIKE 'b%' THEN 2
               WHEN column2 LIKE 'c%' THEN 3
               ELSE 99 END;"""

params = {'list_of_values': list_of_values}

cursor.execute(sql_query, params)
```

Comment: Are you certain that this code even runs?

Comment: yes, the code runs without error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed limit of values in the IN clause, neither in 5.7 or 8.0. The theoretical limit depends on the length of your SQL statement and the value of `max_allowed_packet`.

This is also documented in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html):

"*The number of values in the IN() list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.*"